# The end of 2018 and beginning of 2019 witnessed us in "a lot of moments of ups and downs". how to express the part in the quote in an eloquent way??

Tags: vocabulary

and can I say, "The end of 2018 and 2019 the beginning?"

Comment: No, you can't say '2019 the beginning'. You could try 'Late 2018 and early 2019'.

Answer (score 1):

You may use “roller-coaster” to mean ups and downs - [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roller-coaster). This is often used by media to mean exactly what you are trying to say.

I would suggest the following: We witnessed many roller-coaster moments throughout the end of 2018 and early 2019.

Comment: And many synonyms of roller coaster in this sense - turbulence, commotion, tumult, highs and lows.